# can't read if statement when create a new DOM with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a clone function with jquery and included a deleted button inside it, when i click the delete button it will delete the particular box parent and hide the delete button when the delete button length < 2, i generate unique id for each box start from 1, it work when i delete the box with id in sequence start from 3,2,1 and 4 (from bottom to top box), but the delete button can't hide when i start delete start from 4,1,2,3 (from the top to the bottom), here my code below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var counter = 1;
  var total = 1;
  var el = $('#clone');
  var box = $('.box');
  var container = '.container';
  var deleteBtn = $('#delete');
  
   

  $(document.body).on('click','#clone', function(){
    counter ++;
    total ++;
    var startClone = box.clone(true);
    startClone.appendTo(container);
    box.attr('id','hallo' + counter); 
    $('.box').find('#delete').show();
    deleteBtn.show();
  })
  
  $('#delete').on('click', function(){
    total --;
    $(this).closest('.box').remove();
    console.log(total);
    if(total < 2){
      deleteBtn.hide();
    }else {
      deleteBtn.show();
    } 
  })
})
```

```css
.box {
      background: red;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 5px 0;
    }
    #clone {
      display: block;
    }
    #delete {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box" id="hallo1">
      <button id="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id='clone'>Clone this</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` should be unique. When you clode `box` element there would be multiple buttons with `id` delete and will create issues.

I used class `.delete`. Please check.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 1;
  var el = $('#clone');
  var box = $('#hallo1');
  var container = '.container';
  box.hide(); //Hide the orginal box

  var clone = function(){
    counter++;
    var startClone = box.clone(true);
    startClone.append(counter - 1); //For test purposes. Please remove
    startClone.appendTo(container);
    startClone.attr('id', 'hallo' + counter);
    startClone.show(); //Show the cloned box
    startClone.find('.delete').show();
    toggleDelete();
  }

  var toggleDelete = function(){
    if ($(".delete").length < 2) {
      $(".delete").hide();
    } else {
      $(".delete").show();
    }
  }

  clone();//Clone initaly

  $(document.body).on('click', '#clone', function() {
    clone();
  })

  $('.delete').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.box').remove();
    toggleDelete();
  })
})
```

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

#clone {
  display: block;
}

.delete {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="hallo1">
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
<button id='clone'>Clone this</button>
```

---

**Alternative cleaner Approach:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#clone").click(function() {
    clone();
    toggleDelete();
  });

  $("body").on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $(this).closest('.box').remove();
    toggleDelete();
  })
  
  var toggleDelete = function() {
    if ($(".delete").length < 2) {
      $(".delete").hide();
    } else {
      $(".delete").show();
    }
  }

  var clone = function() {
    $("#container").append('<div class="container"><div class="box"><button class="delete">Delete</button></div></div>');
  }

   clone(); //Call init
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

#clone {
  display: block;
}

.delete {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<button id='clone'>Clone this</button>
```

Comment: What do you mean is not working? Can you describe what did you click step by step?

Comment: i clone 3 box and delete box 1 and 2, then i clone for box 4 and can't delete the box 4

Comment: I just tested on `code snippet` and I can delete #4. I added numbering to avoid confusion. Please check

Comment: sory if i'm not to clear, here's the step that i produced : i clone 2 box (i have 3 box now) and start delete in sequence box 0 and 1 (from top to bottom)and left the box number 2, then i make another 1 clone then box no 4 appears, so i have box 3 and 4 , when i delete box 4 (the bottom one) can't work

Comment: Got it. The reason why you are getting an error coz you are deleting the original object. Which is not ideal.

Comment: Please check the changes ive made. It hides the original box.

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers must be *unique* so assign a CSS then Class Selector can be used to target the element and You should use Event delegation to bind event with dynamic elements.

```
container.on('click', '.delete', function () {
    $(this).closest('.box').remove();
    if ($(".delete").length < 2) {
        $(".delete").hide();
    } else {
        $(".delete").show();
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var el = $('#clone');
  var box = $('.box');
  var container = $('.container');

  $(document.body).on('click', '#clone', function() {
    var startClone = box.eq(0).clone();
    startClone.appendTo(container);
    $('.box').find('.delete').show();
  })

  container.on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $(this).closest('.box').remove();
    if ($(".delete").length < 2) {
      $(".delete").hide();
    } else {
      $(".delete").show();
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

#clone {
  display: block;
}

.delete {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="hallo1">
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
<button id='clone'>Clone this</button>
```